# How to verify specified proxy is used in php script?

Tags: php, proxies

I am trying to force a php script (currently on XAMPP, soon on a dedicated server) to use a certain proxy for outgoing traffic.

On this site i found the following solution for it :

```
stream_context_set_default(['http'=>['proxy'=>'ip:port']]);
```

how do i verify that my script is actually using that proxy?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use fsockopen for this, where you can specify a timeout.

A simple proxy list checker. You can check a list ip:port if that port is opened on that IP.

```
<?php

$fisier = file_get_contents('proxy_list.txt'); // Read the file with the proxy list
$linii = explode("\n", $fisier); // Get each proxy
$fisier = fopen("bune.txt", "a"); // Here we will write the good ones

for($i = 0; $i < count($linii) - 1; $i++) test($linii[$i]); // Test each proxy

function test($proxy)
{
  global $fisier;
  $splited = explode(':',$proxy); // Separate IP and port
  if($con = @fsockopen($splited[0], $splited[1], $eroare, $eroare_str, 3)) 
  {
    fwrite($fisier, $proxy . "\n"); // Check if we can connect to that IP and port
    print $proxy . '<br>'; // Show the proxy
    fclose($con); // Close the socket handle
  }
}

fclose($fisier); // Close the file

?>
```

you may also want to use set_time_limit so that you can run your script for longer.

Code taken from: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php#95605

Just for 1 proxy :

```
function test()
{
  $fisier = fopen("bune.txt", "a"); // Here we will write the good ones
  if($con = @fsockopen($IP, $port, $eroare, $eroare_str, 3)) 
  {
    fwrite($fisier, $proxy . "\n"); // Check if we can connect to that IP and port
    print $proxy . '<br>'; // Show the proxy
    fclose($con); // Close the socket handle
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, how would i check just a single proxy? i am still relatively new to this stuff